# How to add color over CALayer() with alpha value?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, swift3, calayer

I have working slideshow codes with `CALayer()` and I want to add `Brown` color mask over images with `alpha` value. My `CALayer()` codes under below.

```
   let imageLayer = CALayer()
    imageLayer.contents = image.cgImage
    imageLayer.anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero
    imageLayer.bounds = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: optimus)
    imageLayer.position = origin
    imageView.layer.addSublayer(imageLayer)
```

Full code you can see here: https://github.com/Gatada/JBKenBurnsView/blob/master/KenBurns/JBKenBurnsView.swift. Look at 281-286 lines between.

Comment: Could you add a bit more clarity to your description of the issue? What effect are you trying to get - adding a *brown tint* over the images or some kind of animation? What else have you tried? In what ways have they failed? Also, consider using CISepiaTone or another CI filter for the effect you want.

Comment: @dfd added some codes and now adding brown color over image but going with slide need to little fix  look at chat under below question comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.

```
imageLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown.withAlphaComponent(0.8).cgColor //Set alpha you want
```

**Edit:** From your edit code you need to set your `imageLayer2` frame like this.

```
imageLayer2.frame = imageView.bounds
```

Comment: i added but no action , you can see all codes here https://github.com/Gatada/JBKenBurnsView/blob/master/KenBurns/JBKenBurnsView.swift  look at  line 281-286 ty

Comment: i want to add this slideshow view over brown layer with alpha value.

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper Instead of adding layer in imageView using `addSublayer` try once using `insertLayer` like this way `imageView.layer.insertSublayer(imageLayer, at: 0)`

Comment: ty dude i added but no action

Comment: https://github.com/Gatada/JBKenBurnsView/tree/master/KenBurns  you can see here sample project

Comment: https://github.com/Gatada/JBKenBurnsView/blob/master/KenBurns/ViewController.swift

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper Let me check it.

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper Could you show what you want and what your current output in screenshot.

Comment: i downloaded sample project after added your lines after i took a screenshoot. https://postimg.org/image/536fd6u6r/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130791/discussion-between-swiftdeveloper-and-nirav-d).

Comment: i added some codes and need little fix come on chat i wrote there extra codes ty.